# Geany IDE use python 3?... and where is my Tkinter window?

Tags: python

On my Pi that's now updated to a nice recent Raspbian, I am eager to start using the Geany editor for Python. But:

(1) How do I force it to use Python 3.x? I can tell that Geany is using Python 2.x and not 3.x because when I tried "import tkinter" it gave an error saying it couldn't find tkinter... only when I changed it to Tkinter would it work, which I understand means it's running Python 2.x.

(2) When I run my simple graphics tkinter python script (pasted below) in Geany, with Tkinter capitalized since we are in 2.x ... it "runs" ... but simply shows the script window proudly announcing that script completed... and the graphics window created by the script does not appear!  When I do this in Thonny IDE, the graphics window appears.   How do I get Geany to show this script's graphics window correctly?

Giant thanks -- Eric

```
from Tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title('Alien')
c = Canvas(window, height = 300, width=400)
c.pack()
body=c.create_oval(100,150,300,250,fill='green')
eye=c.create_oval(170,70,230,130,fill='white')
eyeball=c.create_oval(190,90,210,110,fill='black')
mouth=c.create_oval(150,220,250,240,fill='red')
neck=c.create_line(200,150,200,130)
hat=c.create_polygon(180,75,220,75,200,20,fill='blue')

def mouth_open():
    c.itemconfig(mouth,fill='black')
def mouth_close():
    c.itemconfig(mouth,fill='red')

def blink(event):
    c.itemconfig(eye, fill='green')
    c.itemconfig(eyeball, state=HIDDEN)
def unblink(event):
    c.itemconfig(eye, fill='white')
    c.itemconfig(eyeball, state=NORMAL)

words=c.create_text(200,280,text='I am an alien!')
def steal_hat():
    c.itemconfig(hat,state=HIDDEN)
    c.itemconfig(words, text='Give me my hat back!')

window.attributes('-topmost',1)

def burp(event):
    mouth_open()
    c.itemconfig(words,text="Burp!")
c.bind_all('<Button-1>', burp)

c.bind_all('<KeyPress-a>',blink)
c.bind_all('<KeyPress-z>',unblink)


def eye_control(event):
    key=event.keysym
    if key=='Up':
        c.move(eyeball,0,-1)
    if key=='Down':
        c.move(eyeball,0,1)
    if key=='Left':
        c.move(eyeball,-1,0)
    if key=='Right':
        c.move(eyeball,1,0)
c.bind_all('<Key>',eye_control)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34317310/377125), go to *Build* → *Set Build Commands* and change references to `python` to `python3` in the **Compile** and **Execute** sections. After that, Tk will work as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                              command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

While this will change build and run commands to use Python 3, it *won't* modify Geany's Python template. Geany stores its templates in `/usr/share/geany/templates/files`

Comment: thanks! I will mark this correct because it fixed my question (1)... But it didn't fix my question (2)...   I shouldn't have combined two questions in the same.  So now I will post the question (2) as a separate question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The above left my question #2 un-answered. But, I found the answer to that one on a different site:

I had not put this line:

window.mainloop()

at the bottom of the script. This causes no problem when you are using an IDE that is built on Tk/Tkinter, because it has some kind of mainloop going by default. but if you want to run it in an IDE or setting other than that, you need that mainloop of course.

Comment: It might be better simply to delete the second question from your original post since you've posted it separately as a new question. This is also easier for future visitors who find your question if they have the same problem to avoid the two issues getting mixed together.